# Kendo grid change style cell data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, client-side-templating, knockout-templating

I have a very basic kendo grid. I am using template feature to style cell data. What I want to do is style "Edit" in red and "Delete" in green color.

**GRID CODE**

```
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: createRandomUserData(),
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'Id',
                    fields: {
                        FirstName: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        Action: {
                            type: "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name"
            },
            {
                field: "Action",
                title: "Action",
                template: "<span style='color:red'>#: Action #</span>"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

How can I do it. I am unable to separate cell data.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1338/

Comment: Regarding your JSFiddle... What about the cells that contain both Edit and Delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying directly the color what I suggest you to do is define several CSS classes that do the styling.

Example:

```
.Edit {
    color: red;
}

.Delete {
    color: green;
}

.Edit.Delete {
    color: blue;
}
```

And specify in the template which `class` to use.

```
template: "<span class='#: Action #'>#: Action #</span>"
```

This uses `red` when they are `Edit`, `green` if `Delete` and `blue` if both.

And you JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/298nZ/

**EDIT**: If you want to split/format per word, then you need a little programming. Basically you might do it as follow.

```
// Convert words separated by spaces into an array
var words = data.Action.split(" ");
// Iterate on array elements for emitting the HTML
$.each(words, function(idx, word) {
    // emit HTML using template syntax
    <span class="#: word #">#: word #</span>
});
```

All this needs to be wrapped in a template and you get:

```
<script type="text/kendo-script" id="template">
    # console.log("data", data, data.Action); #
    # var words = data.Action.split(" "); #
    # $.each(words, function(idx, word) { #
        <span class='#= word #'>#= word #</span>&nbsp;
    # }); #
</script>
```

And your grid definition:

```
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: createRandomUserData(),
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'Id',
                fields: {
                    FirstName: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    Action: {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name"
        },
        {
            field: "Action",
            title: "Action",
            template: $("#template").html()
        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

The JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/298nZ/1/

Comment: Great !! But I do not want a third color. When Edit and Delete both are present I want Edit in red and Delete in green.

Comment: very great !! Thanks for such a smart answer.